# Solving for $d$ from $a=r^2\arccos{\frac{d}{2r}}-\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I would like to solve this equation for d with a given r value. Is there a way to write in explicit form? $a$ is of course a known value, I am a little rusty on trigonometry.

$$a  = r^2\arccos{\frac{d}{2r}}-\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}
$$

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: corrected the equation

Comment: Sorry, I tried to switch to x as the unknown

Comment: This one is ugly.  First of all go ahead and set $x = (d/2)$ and solve for $x$.  Second, set $\theta = $ arc$\cos (x/r).$  Third, notice that $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{(r^2 - x^2)/r^2}.$  I see no magic wand to wave here.

Comment: You'd better express $a/r^2$ as a function of $d/2r$. I recognize the equation of the area of a circular segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation bing highly transcendental, there is no analytical solution (remember that this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$) and you will need some numerical method.

However, we can make *approximations*. Let $d=2rx$ to make
$$\cos ^{-1}(x)-x \sqrt{1-x^2}=k \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\frac a{r^2}$$
Using Taylor expansions built around $x=0$, the lhs write
$$\frac{\pi }{2}-2 x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{20}+\frac{x^7}{56}+\frac{5
   x^9}{576}+\frac{7 x^{11}}{1408}+\frac{21 x^{13}}{6656}+\frac{11
   x^{15}}{5120}+O\left(x^{17}\right)$$ which is quite good (draw the two functions).

Now, using series reversion, we should have (I could have added more terms)
$$x=t+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{13 t^5}{120}+\frac{493 t^7}{5040}+\frac{37369
   t^9}{362880}+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$ where $t=\frac {\pi-2k}4$.

Trying for a few values of $k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 0.928261 &  1.000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.884346 &  0.910264 \\
 0.10 & 0.842841 &  0.856758 \\
 0.15 & 0.803428 &  0.811397 \\
 0.20 & 0.765836 &  0.770519 \\
 0.25 & 0.729828 &  0.732608 \\
 0.30 & 0.695202 &  0.696855 \\
 0.35 & 0.661782 &  0.662761 \\
 0.40 & 0.629417 &  0.629992 \\
 0.45 & 0.597977 &  0.598311 \\
 0.50 & 0.567349 &  0.567540 \\
 0.55 & 0.537436 &  0.537543 \\
 0.60 & 0.508153 &  0.508212 \\
 0.65 & 0.479429 &  0.479460 \\
 0.70 & 0.451198 &  0.451214 \\
 0.75 & 0.423406 &  0.423414 \\
 0.80 & 0.396003 &  0.396007 \\
 0.85 & 0.368946 &  0.368948 \\
 0.90 & 0.342198 &  0.342199 \\
 0.95 & 0.315725 &  0.315725 \\
 1.00 & 0.289494 &  0.289494
\end{array}
\right)$$ This seems to be quite decent except for small values of $k$ that is to say for $x$ close to $1$.

To improve it, doing the same kind of work around $x=1$, the lhs write
$$\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}  (1-x)^{3/2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}  (1-x)^{5/2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{56}(1-x)^{7/2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{288 }(1-x)^{9/2}+\cdots$$ and series reversion will give
$$\sqrt{1-x}=u-\frac{u^3}{20}+\frac{81 u^5}{5600}-\frac{1171 u^7}{201600}+\cdots$$ where $u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3 k}{4 \sqrt{2}}}$.
which gives  better estimates for small values of $k$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 1.000000 &  1.000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.911847 &  0.910264 \\
 0.10 & 0.860754 &  0.856758 \\
 0.15 & 0.818272 &  0.811397 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d = 2r \cos \theta$

$$a = r^2\theta - r\cos \theta r\sin \theta$$

$$a = r^2(\theta - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta))$$

Hence the equation becomes

$$2\theta - \sin(2\theta) = \frac{2a}{r^2}$$

Generally, equations of this form cannot be solved analytically, but it's fairly easy to graph and get an approximate value depending on the values of $a, r$. Since it is a monotone function, there is exactly one solution to this

The graph of $y = x - \sin x$ oscillates between the graphs of $y=x+1$ and $y = x - 1$, touching them at maxima/minima points of $\sin x$

Comment: I was wondering if there was an analytical solution. I've graphed it already and ended up approximating it. It just didn't look that elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reassuring me.

Comment: It looks like the problem is finding the diameter of a circle such that a chord of length r leaves a segment of area a

Comment: Maybe there's other ways of formulating the question - to get an easy answer?

Comment: given two identical circles of radius r, the area of their intersections, the direction of the segment that connects the first center to the second center, and the position of the first center I must find the distance d between centers